# Automatically change Ubuntu wallpaper at a certain hour

Tags: desktop-background

So I am using Ubuntu and I have encountered many softwares and workarounds for changing wallpapers automatically, **BUT**, it all pertains to *time intervals* and what I want is by *certain time period*.

Like I got this wallpapers for dawn, morning, noon, afternoon, dusk and night. And I want to set my wallpapers that each of them transitions at a certain hour, e.g. 4 am, 8 am, 12 pm, 3 pm, 6 pm and 8 pm. **NOT** through *every 3 hours* or so, PLEASE.

I encountered *wallch*, *SyncWall* and *Variety*, but didn't see my intended purpose. Syncwall was close enough, except that it causes a bug with dual monitor wallpapers.

Any other apps/softwares that you could suggest? A manual script would also do, if you may.

Comment: I would believe the following 2 steps: 1. You change the wallpaper with a gsetting, so find out how to do that. 2. add that command to a script and execute that script from /etc/crontab at the given times with a specific wallpaper.

Comment: I'm sorry @Rinzwind but I'm an amateur when it comes to Linux commands, but I have wide experience in programming. Maybe if you could point out the specific scripts that I should code, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I'm not sure, but maybe you have to install `dconf` first

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-cli
   ```
2. Edit your `crontab`

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```
3. Add an entry for each background image

   ```
   */5 4,5,6,7 * * *   /path/to/change_wallpaper '/path/of/your/wallpaper/for/4am'
   */5 8,8,9,10,11 * * *   /path/to/change_wallpaper '/path/of/your/wallpaper/for/8am'
   */5 12,13,14 * * *   /path/to/change_wallpaper '/path/of/your/wallpaper/for/12am'
   */5 15,16,17 * * *   /path/to/change_wallpaper '/path/of/your/wallpaper/for/3pm'
   */5 18,19 * * *   /path/to/change_wallpaper '/path/of/your/wallpaper/for/6pm'
   */5 20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3 * * *   /path/to/change_wallpaper '/path/of/your/wallpaper/for/8pm'
   ```

   - The interval is set to 5 minutes (`*/5`).
   - The lowest possible interval is 1 minute (`*/1` or `*`)
4. Save and close your crontab editor
5. Create the script

   ```
   nano change_wallpaper
   ```
6. Add the code below

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -e
   user=$(whoami)

   fl=$(find /proc -maxdepth 2 -user "$user" -name environ -print -quit)
   for i in {1..5}
   do
     fl=$(find /proc -maxdepth 2 -user "$user" -name environ -newer "$fl" -print -quit)
   done

   export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS "$fl" | cut -d= -f2-)

   IMG="file://$1"
   if [ "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri)" != "$FILE" ]; then
       dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri" "'file://${IMG}'"
      # gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "'$IMG'"
   fi
   ```

   - The script works with `dconf` or `gsettings`. You can switch between both methods. Simply **move** the `#` in the front of the `gsettings …` line to the `dconf …` line
7. Make it executable

   ```
   chmod +x change_wallpaper
   ```
8. Test the script in your crontab

   - Edit your crontab again

     ```
     crontab -e
     ```
   - Add the (temporary) line below

     ```
     */1 * * * *   /path/to/change_wallpaper '/path/of/any/wallpaper'
     ```
   - Close the crontab editor
   - Wait a minute
9. If the script works, remove the test entry

   - Edit your crontab again

     ```
     crontab -e
     ```
   - Remove the (temporary) line below

     ```
     */1 * * * *   /path/to/change_wallpaper '/path/of/any/wallpaper'
     ```
   - Close the crontab editor

<sub>Script partially taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/198508/367165)</sub>

Comment: The change_wallpaper script for 1 minute worked! I'm just gonna see if the "dusk" would work now, thanks. :)

Comment: I was wondering but when I tried installing `dconf`, it said that `E: Package 'dconf' has no installation candidate`. But I opted the `gsettings` anyway.

Comment: Sorry, the package is dconf-cli

Comment: I just noticed but, if I turned on the PC after 4am, then the scheduled change wallpaper won't take effect.  Is there any other way to force the scheduled task?

Comment: I have improved my answer. The interval is now every 5 minutes (`*/5`). The lowest value is 1 minute. And I have added a test in the script to avoid useless changes.

Comment: I see, thanks . . . . but may I know what's the interval (1 min ~ 5 mins) for?

Comment: The script is started every 5 minutes, and inside the script checks, if the wallpaper should be changed.

Comment: Therefore you will see the right wallpaper with a maximum delay of five minutes

Comment: Actually, the new script for `change_wallpaper` didn't worked for me, so I reverted back to the previous one that you gave me. I think that the `if` statement wasn't that necessary on my PC.

Comment: Hey, do you have any ideas with relating to this? http://askubuntu.com/q/739607/442175
It suddenly appeared, but your script worked just fine for about a year.

Comment: Hello, your script doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? Any knowledge why?