# Unity greeter wallpaper change every minute

Tags: unity, lightdm, desktop-background

I have script that changes Unity Greeter wallpaper location every minut, but problem is that it doesn't show new wallpaper unless i login in to any user account and switch back to Login screen (Win+L). Is it possible to refresh new wallpaper without logging in user account?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://askubuntu.com/a/664539/367165

Comment: Thanks, but that answer is for user wallpaper. I successfully managed to write that on my own. Unfortunately what i need is to change Unity Greeter wallpaper and that is what gives me trouble.

Comment: Oh, sorry. **:)**

Comment: Does your scrpit  have the greeter reload its configuration file for the background as part of changing it? That would be nesecary for the new background to take effect.

Comment: @ianorlin No it did not have. Thanks for idea. I found diferent solution for my needs, so it's not actual for me anymore, but i will keep this in mind if i need this again.