# How do I make a shell script that changes the background at night?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, process

All I want to do is create a shell script that runs in the background.
It turns on when I log in/on boot up.

Every hour it checks the time for 9:00 pm, (if you can figure out sun sets and rises that would be great), if it is past it switches the background.

Then it changes the back if it is past 9:00 pm. But past 7:00 am it would turn that background off.

Basically just switching between 2 backgrounds.
How can I do this?

Comment: Okay, thanks don't vote down I'll remove it if that question helps.

Comment: Okay, that script won't work.

Comment: Wait wrong directory haha

Comment: Error:```/home/jpesquibel/Pictures/change_wallpaper: line 11: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
/home/jpesquibel/Pictures/change_wallpaper: line 14: [: 'file:///home/jpesquibel/Pictures/rd_statues.png': unary operator expected```

Comment: I noticed an error in the proposed solution which I have just corrected (`!= "$FILE"]` needs to be `!= "$FILE" ]` - the whitespace around `[` and `]` is required

Comment: okay, but this script seems to work

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/739607/dconf-warning-failed-to-commit-changes-to-dconf-the-given-address-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

[Automatically change Ubuntu wallpaper at a certain hour](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664411/automatically-change-ubuntu-wallpaper-at-a-certain-hour#664539)

But with this script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
user=$(whoami)

fl=$(find /proc -maxdepth 2 -user "$user" -name environ -print -quit)
for i in {1..5}
do
  fl=$(find /proc -maxdepth 2 -user "$user" -name environ -newer "$fl" -print -quit)
done

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS "$fl" | cut -d= -f2-)

IMG=$1
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "'file://${IMG}'"
```

Comment: This should be another answer to *that* question.

Comment: Can you comment this code over to the current answer to _that_ question for me?

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation.